# Rails - How to avoid using hidden_fields in the view to pass values to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

Is there a way I can avoid the `hidden_field` method of passing values in the view to a controller? I would prefer a controller method for security reasons. Unfortunately value pairing `@variables` is not supported in `strong_parameters`.

> **EDIT 6/18 1:00 PM EST**
>
> 1. I've renamed my `garages` controller to `appointments`
> 2. `cars_controller` no longer creates a new `appointment` (formally `garages`). A new appointment is created in the
>    `appointments_controller`

My current structure

---

**routes**

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
resources :techs, only: [:index, :show], shallow: true do
    resources :cars, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

resources :appointments

```
#For searchkick
resources :cars, only: [:show] do
    collection do
        get 'search'
    end
end

root "home#index"

end
```

---

**models**

**tech.rb**

```
class Tech < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchkick

    has_many :appointments
    has_many :customers, :through => :appointments
    has_many :service_menus
    has_many :services
    has_many :cars
end
```

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tech
    belongs_to :service_menu

    has_many :cars, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**car.rb**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :tech
  has_many :appointments 
end
```

**appointment.rb**

```
class Garage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :tech
  belongs_to :car
end
```

---

**controllers**

**cars_controller**

```
def new
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @tech = Tech.find(params[:tech_id])

  @appointment = Garage.new 
end
```

**appointments_controller**

```
def create
  @appointment = current_customer.appointments.build(appointment_params)

  if @appointment.save
    redirect_to appointments_path, notice:  "You car has been added to this appointment." 
  else
    redirect_to appointments_path, notice:  "Uh oh, an error has occured." 
  end
end

private

def appointment_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:tech_id, :service_id, :car_id, ...and a bunch of other keys here)
end
```

---

**views**

**cars.new.html**

> Please note this form passes hidden values to the `appointment_controller`.
>
> Value from `@car.name` and other alike are not from a `text_field` but rather a pre-defined value based on selections from a previous page which is store in the `cars` db.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@appointment, { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :tech_id, value: @tech.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :car_id, value: @car.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :service_id, value: @car.service.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :customer_car, value: current_customer.car %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :customer_street_address, value: current_customer.street_address %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :customer_city, value: current_customer.city %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :customer_state, value: current_customer.state %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :customer_zip_code, value: current_customer.zip_code %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :service_name, value: @car.service.service_menu.name %>    
        <%= f.hidden_field :car_name, value: @car.name %>
    
        <%= **And a bunch of other hidden values here which are too long to list**  %>
    
    <%= f.submit "Add to appointment", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    <% end %>
```

**service.html**

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

**_form.html**

```
<%= simple_form_for @service do |f| %>
  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label "Select service category" %>
    <br>
    
    <%= collection_select(:service, :service_menu_id, ServiceMenu.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true }) %>

    <%= f.fields_for :cars do |task| %>
      <%= render 'car_fields', :f => task %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add New Car', f, :cars, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  </div><br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_car_fields.html**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
        <%= f.label :hours %>
        <%= f.select :hours, '0'..'8' %>
        <%= f.label :minutes %>
        <%= f.select :minutes, options_for_select( (0..45).step(15), selected: f.object.minutes) %><br>
        <%= f.label :price %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :price, :value => (number_with_precision(f.object.price, :precision => 2) || 0) %> <br>
        <%= f.label :details %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :details %></div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Car", f, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :tech_id, value: current_tech.id %>
  <br>
    <hr>
</div>
```

---

**> Edit 7/14 1:30 pm EST**

**Brief Synopsis on this specific function of the application**

1. A `customer` clicks through a list of services a `tech` has to offer
2. The `customer` selects a service for example *brakes* which is a service a `tech` has listed in his profile.
3. The attributes for *brakes* are listed in the `cars` db
4. `cars` `belongs_to` to `techs`
5. The `customer` can save *brakes* which is an attribribute of a `techs` `car` to a `appointment`
6. A good number of predefined values from `tech`, the `customer`'s street address, etc..., and the `car` are pre-loaded in the `form` for storing in the `appointments` table.
7. `appointment` acts as a *histories* table. So if the `tech` decides to modify any one of his `services` in this example *brakes*, the `appointments` tables will remain untouched for the *brakes* entry.
8. Once the `customer` selects the `Add to appointment` button, it will save all of the predefined values from `tech`, `customer`, and `car` attributes (in this example *brakes*) to the `appointments` db.

---

Another approach to this would be to get rid of the `strong parameters` altogether and do the following:

```
def create
    @appointment = Garage.create(tech_id: @car.service.tech.id,
                                      customer_id: current_customer.id,
                                      customer_street_address: current_customer.street_address,
                                      customer_city: current_customer.city,
                                      customer_state: current_customer.state,
                                      customer_zip_code: current_customer.zip_code,
                                      customer_phone_number: current_customer.phone_number,
                                      customer_location_type: "WILL ADD LATER",
                                      customer_latitude: current_customer.latitude,
                                      customer_longitude: current_customer.longitude,                                      
                                      service_id: @car.service.id,
                                      service_name: @car.service.name,
                                      car_id: @car.id,
                                      car_name: @car.name,
                                      car_time_duration: @car.time_duration,
                                      price: @car.price,
                                      car_details: @car.details)
  
    if @appointment.save
      redirect_to techs_path, notice:  "This service has been saved." 
    elsif 
      redirect_to tech_path, notice:  "Uh oh, an error has occurred." 
    end
  end
```

Please let me know if you require further details.

Comment: I looks like a lot of your hidden fields map to a value in `current_customer`. Are any of these values being changed in the form? If not you should probably just be using current_customer in the controller which is already available.

Comment: `current_customer.???` comes from the `Devise` gem for user login and registration. There are `@variables` coming from multiple controllers so it would be best that I place them in the `garages` db. None of the `@variable` values are manually inputted by users but rather they are a predefined collection of data based on a user's selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve my issue, my latest edit from my initial post stated the following:

> **EDIT 6/18 1:00 PM EST**
>
> 1. I've renamed my `garages_controller` to `appointments_controller`
> 2. `cars_controller` no longer creates a new appointment (formally garages). A new appointment is created in the `appointments_controller`

Only hidden_field i'm passing is the `car_id` in the *appointments view /new.html.erb* `<%= f.hidden_field :car_id, value: @car.id %>`.

In the `appointments_controller`, I'm assigning all the `car` attributes doing the following.

```
def create
    @appointment = current_customer.appointments.build(appointment_params)
    @appointment.tech_id = @appointment.car.service.tech.id
    @appointment.price = @appointment.car.price
    @appointment.car_name = @appointment.car.name
    @appointment.car_details = @appointment.car.details

    if @appointment.save
        redirect_to appointments_path, notice:  "Thank you booking your appointment." 
    else
        redirect_to appointments_path, notice:  "Uh oh, an error has occurred. Please try again or contact us for further assistance" 
    end
end
```

Thank you all for your responses.
I should've known better. :(

Answer (score 1):

I can think of some methods you could use to avoid this `form` bloated with `hidden_field`s:

- Share data between controllers in the user's session, pretty much like a shopping cart in an e-commerce application.
- If you prefer to preserve the statelessness of the application, create a model to temporarily store these informations; this way you'll only need to include one `hidden_field` in the `form`.
- Use JavaScript to make the requests, storing the data in local objects and passing them as JSON when needed (this is trivial using AngularJS).

Whichever method you choose, keep in mind that storing a lot of state in a web application usually is a code smell. You can always rethink your application so you don't need to keep so much context.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an examples of your suggestion especially the shopping cart method? I have update my post with details on the application's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could move that stuff into a callback and only pass the customer_id and car_id with the form. This way garage instance will know about it's customer and car parents and you can do something like:

```
class Garage < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :copy_stuff

  private

  def copy_stuff
    self.customer_street_address = customer.street_address
    self.car_name = car.name
    # and so on                   
  end
end
```

Comment: I've renamed my 'garages' controller to 'appointments'. 'cars_controller` no longer creates a new _appointment_ (formally `garages`). A new `appointment` is created in the `appointments_controller`. 

I've applied your suggestion. Since I'm using the gem `Device` for user registration and logins, `customer.street_address` would be `current_customer.street_address`. I am receiving follow error.

`undefined local variable or method `current_customer for #<Appointment`. `current_customer` is available definitely available because it's accessible from the `new.html.erb`

Comment: current_customer is only available from controller/view. You should pass the customer id from the form/controller: `customer_id: current_customer.id` and then reference `customer` from the model. (Not the current_customer.)

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way I can avoid the hidden_field method of passing values
>   in the view to a controller?

You can disable those fields in the HTML/view by adding attribute `disabled: true` to the hidden input field tags to achieve what you asked for.

Not sure about the syntax exactly, but should be something like this for example

```
f.hidden_field :tech_id, value: @tech.id, disabled: true
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? Maybe put it on Github as example, then users could try it out.

Comment: I posted my solution above. Thank you.